# put country dropdown in phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2

sayhello.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <h2>Wholesale and Dealer Inquiries Form</h2>
 </head>
 <body>
<table align="center">
<form action="<?php echo $block- 
>getBaseUrl().'wholesaleapplication/index/post/';?>" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td><label> Business Name </label></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="name"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><label> Contact Name </label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="cname"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td> <label> E-mail </label></td>
         <td><input type="email" name="email"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td> <label> Address </label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="address">
         <label> Street Address </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="address2">
         <label> Street Address  line 2</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="city">
         <label>city</label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="state">
         <label>state/province</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="zipcode">
         <label>postal zip/code</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="areacode">
         <label>area code</label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="phonenumber">
         <label>phone number</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td> <label class="form-label form-label-left form-label-auto" id="label_9" for="input_9"> Website </label></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="website"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> <label> Reseller Permit </label></td>
         <td><input type="text"  name="reseller"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td> <label> Description of Business </label></td>
         <td><textarea  name="description" ></textarea></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td> <label> Additional Questions and Comments </label></td>
         <td><textarea name="additional"  ></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> <label> click to edit </label></td>
         <td><input type="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><button  type="submit" name="submit">
          Submit
        </button></td>
    </tr>

</form>
```

country dropdowncode

```
<?php $_countries = 
Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
loadData()
toOptionArray(false) ?>
<?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>">
            <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

i want drop down near zip code in phtml file where to keep this country code?

Comment: you have tried Magento 1 code>

Comment: can you please share me magento2 code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento already has a block class which is available to provide country dropdown.

In your phtml file, call the block and  you will  get country dropdown.

```
<?php $countryBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Directory\Block\Data');?>

<?= $countryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country');?>
```

You can set default `$defValue,$name,$id` as per as your wish.

Comment: i have to keep this code in sayhello.phtml  file right?

Comment: yes, just you have to paste this code

Comment: thankyou it works

Comment: now i have to pass this in post varilable so what will be the name of the variable

Comment: It works +1 from me.

Comment: It is working fine in my Magento_Contct template file, how to get country Name instead of Country code inside the email template. By using {{var data.country_id}} it is showing country code.