# Magento2: How to get country list in custom HTML template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, html, countries

I need to display a country list with **dropdown** in the **custom** knockout HTML template.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262785/put-country-dropdown-in-phtml-file-in-magento2).

Magento already provide some inbuilt solution for this.

```
<?php $countryBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Directory\Block\Data');?>

<?= $countryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country');?>
```

You can set default `$defValue,$name,$id` as per as your wise.

Comment: In php we can do that, but how to move this data to HTML file?

Comment: Thanks it's work.

Comment: @RaviSoni Happy Coding.

Comment: Hello @Mayur, have any idea for this question.:    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313382/magento2-place-order-only-selected-items-from-cart

Comment: @RaviSoni Right now I don't know but if there then I will post soon.

Comment: Thank you.......