# How to get value for dropdown in custom form?

Tags: magento2, forms, dropdown-attribute

customform.phtml

```
<div class="field country required">
    <label class="label" for="country"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input name="country" id="country" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Country') ?>"
               value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')
                   ->getPostValue('country')) ?>"
               class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Country dropdown:

```
<?php $countryBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Directory\Block\Data');?>

<?= $countryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country');?>
```

as per: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262790

How to put the dropdown in the form and get the selected country as $post variable / value?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it. In case somebody needs it:

In block

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;

    }

    public function getAvailableCountries()
    {
        $collection = $this->countryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*');

        return $collection;
    }
```

In template

```
                <?php $countries = $block->getAvailableCountries(); ?>
                <select name="country" id="country">
                    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
                    <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $country->getCountryId(); ?>">
                            <?php echo $country->getName(); ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
```

Hope it helps